# Details of all apps in App Store

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, app-store

Is there a way to get the details of all apps available in App Store (Google Play/ Apple App Store/ Windows Store)? Is there any RSS Feed or a service that could be utilized for this.

Comment: As @Prasad said, no, this isn't possible. This would be a HUGE bandwidth strain on the servers of whoever owned the respective store (think--700,000 apps), and would be of little to no benefit to them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply answer is NO, There is no such way to grab the application information in the AppStore, Google Play or Windows store.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the rss feed of iPhone app's using this [link](http://itunes.apple.com/rss). You can generate the rss feed url according to your need.
2. For Android refer this [link](http://androinica.com/2009/07/tips-follow-the-android-market-with-an-rss-reader-for-beginners/)
3. For windows refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452973.aspx)